# Is it normal to have a lot of Compute Engine API requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was looking at my API & Services dashboard and I see a lot of requests to the Compute Engine API. I created a VM a few days ago but have stopped it. However I am still seeing ~50 requests in the last hour. and overall from creating the instance and adding stuff there has been ~18,000 requests in total.

Is this normal behavior? Can I be billed for this amount of requests? Is there a limit?

Comment: Yes there is limit of API requests per day for each & every API. But luckily there is no Quota limit for Compute Engine API,its unlimited. So i think no worries you would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of API requests. Those that your code (Cloud SDK) create or service to service requests and those made by Google Cloud to manage/monitor your services.

> Is this normal behavior?

For Google Cloud management, yes. My account has millions of API requests.

> Can I be billed for this amount of requests?

Yes. If you click on the "Compute Engine API" from "APIs & Services". However, I am not sure how the breakdown in pricing is calculated. Some services such as Stackdriver show "no billing information".

> Is there a limit?

For Google Management and Monitoring API calls, I am not sure but I believe that Google does not limit itself but I might be wrong to prevent errant services (bugs).

For API calls that you or your services generate, yes for both a quota and request per second. Rate limits are enforced every 100 seconds and are refreshed. This limit is per project: [details](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits). Once you exceed these limits (quota/rate) your API calls will receive 403 (rateLimitExceeded) until the [quota is refreshed](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage).