# Is it possible to trace Google Compute Engine API Calls to see their source?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Our Google account has not had a VM in service for at least several months - we may have tested one early in 2020 or sometime in 2019 for a short period. The service was enabled and a week ago started having a lot of API calls:

[image: See traffic graph on the left]

Here are more specific graphs that show the actual API calls being executed, and show that they're executed by an anonymous user (i.e. not using the API keys).

[image: Compute Engine Graphs]

Why would these be executed all of a sudden, without any activity on our part having triggered them?

This other answer indicates that Google executes API calls to check how much capacity you're using, so is it possible that Google is checking hundreds of times every hour to see what virtual machines are up? [Is it normal to have a lot of Compute Engine API requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171088/is-it-normal-to-have-a-lot-of-compute-engine-api-requests)

Comment: These API calls are from Google Cloud. Google tracks its own API calls to manage your project resources. You might say "but I don't have any XXX". Google is making an API call to  determine that. If you enable a service such as Compute Engine, Google will start making API calls to that service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@John is right, These calls are coming from GCP and are mostly for the purpose of checking for what's in the project.

You could check to see where that methods are being called in the metrics overview.

[image]

You could then look at the metrics to see what they are.

In Google Cloud, APIs are tracked both for usage and for security reasons (who is accessing what and when), Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380373) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response - Just accepting now as I forgot to accept your answer when you posted it.